# Solaris kstat - great tool, not much reference?

Tags: solaris

I am trying to use kstat for Solaris 10 monitoring, but it is pretty tough trying to find reference materials on what the individual codes decode to and what they mean. Can anyone recommend a good source for this ?

Cheers.

Comment: What version of Solaris are you running?

Comment: The version is Solaris 10.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Solaris Tunable Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0404/index.html), but  that's [apparently incomplete](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5346458). kstats are defined by individual drivers, so the ultimate source is [the kernel source itself](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/search?q=kstat&project=%2Fonnv).